# ReactJS + NodeJS (express): who does the api calls?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

first post on here!

I have a question: I'm building a personal project and I already built my nodejs (express) backend and currently building the ReactJS frontend.

My frontend is setup to do API calls to my backend and I'm wondering how they really work.
Ex: I have a login page and it asks my backend to validate credentials when I press the login button.

Is my browser doing the api call to the backend or does this take place on my frontend server?

Frontend is reachable at localhost:3001, backend is localhost:3000.

If I visit localhost:3001/login from my PC, login works. If I try to login through my phone (visiting 192.168.1.xx:3001), axios gives me back Network error.

Comment: If your URL in the frontend app is configured as `localhost:3000/api`, for example - browser will try to reach that address and port. And eventually, you are not running nodejs backend app on your phone so when you load your page on it - localhost will not be reachable. So you need to reconfigure URLS in your frontend app to use api address that will be reachable. If you have static dhcp address from router - use 192.x.x.x:port address then.